# Filter a javascript array by an object only containing a subset of the array properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, filtering

I have an array of objects that have many properties. I would like to be able to find the matching items, based on a filter object that only contains a subset of the arrays properties. For Example, i have a customer

```
let Customer = {
    Name: "John Doe",
    Age: 80,
    Hair: "Red",
    Gender: "Male",

};
```

And i have my search object:

```
let searchObject ={
    Hair: "Red",
    Gender: "Male"
}
```

I want to be able to find inside my array, all customers that match searchObject, without having to do:

```
this.array.filter(z=>z.Hair == searchObject.Hair && z.Gender == searchObject.Gender);
```

I would like for it to be when searchObject adds more properties, it automatically filters on those too

Comment: "only contains a subset of the ~arrays~ object's properties"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `every()` on `Object.keys()` of `searchObject` inside and check if all the values of keys in `searchObject` matches with corresponding values of object in array.

Below in the snippet I have two object with different `Gender`

```js
let array = [{
    Name: "John Doe",
    Age: 80,
    Hair: "Red",
    Gender: "Male",
},{
    Name: "Marry",
    Age: 80,
    Hair: "Red",
    Gender: "Female",
}]

let searchObject ={
    Hair: "Red",
    Gender: "Male"
}

const res = array.filter(x => Object.keys(searchObject).every(k => x[k] === searchObject[k]));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the entries and filter by the key/value pairs.

```js
var customers = [{ Name: "John Doe", Age: 80, Hair: "Red", Gender: "Male" }],
    searchObject = { Hair: "Red", Gender: "Male" },
    search = Object.entries(searchObject),
    result = customers.filter(o => search.every(([k, v]) => o[k] === v));

console.log(result);
```